# How to use "defaultSortOrder " in antdTable?

Tags: antd

**I want to show data in ascending order can anyone help me out to solve this?**

**My table code is :**

```
const columns = [

      {
        title: "Pass date",
        dataIndex: "passDate",
        sorter: (a, b) =>
          moment(a.passDate) &&
          moment(a.passDate) > moment(b.passDate) &&
          moment(b.passDate)
            ? 1
            : -1,
        render: (name, item, i) => {
          return (
            <span>
              {item.passDate}&nbsp;&nbsp;

            </span>
          );
        }
      },
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for just string and number:

```
 const columns = [
  {
    title: "Pass date",
    dataIndex: "passDate",
    sorter: (a, b) =>
      moment(a.passDate) &&
      moment(a.passDate) > moment(b.passDate) &&
      moment(b.passDate)
        ? 1
        : -1,
    defaultSortOrder: "descend",
    render: (name, item, i) => {
      return (
        <span>
          {item.passDate}&nbsp;&nbsp;

        </span>
      );
    }
  }
]
```

If you want to sort date or date time (like 12/12/2019 format), try this:

```
const columns = [
  {
    title: "Pass date",
    dataIndex: "passDate",
    sorter: (a, b) =>
      moment(a.passDate) &&
      moment(a.date).unix() - moment(b.date).unix() &&
      moment(b.passDate)
        ? 1
        : -1,
    defaultSortOrder: "descend",
    render: (name, item, i) => {
      return (
        <span>
          {item.passDate}&nbsp;&nbsp;

        </span>
      );
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Its not giving me right result can u say alternative way?

Comment: i want in table column data will be show in ascending order

Comment: So you can change the value to "ascend" in defaultSortOrder attribute. When you use defaultSortOrder, this column will be sorted at default. You can try this on https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-lumiere-36slq.  What is the result you want to render ?

Comment: i've just edited the answer, sorry because i don't understand your question clearly